# A function that induces oscillations around the non-trivial zeros of $\zeta(s)$.

Tags: number-theory, roots, riemann-zeta

The function:

$$f(s) ={\frac { \left( \zeta \left( s \right)  \right) ^{ \left( \zeta
 \left( 1-s \right)  \right) ^{-1}}}{ \left( \zeta \left( 1-s \right) 
 \right) ^{ \left( \zeta \left( s \right)  \right) ^{-1}}}}$$

gives the following plot for $\Re\left(f(\frac12+i\,t) \right)$:

[image]

The function heavily oscillates around each non-trivial zero ($\rho$). I wondered about the 'width' of these oscillations and from plots a bit higher up, e.g.:

[image]

it appears that the nearer the $\rho$s are to each other, the wider spread the oscillations around them are. The $\rho$s in this domain:

> 141.123707404
>       143.111845808
>       146.000982487
>       147.422765343
>       150.053520421
>       150.925257612
>       153.024693811
>       156.112909294
>       157.597591818
>       158.849988171

I know that $\rho$s tend to repel each other, so could there be a correlation between the distance to their neighbour(s) and the 'width' (or 'energy') of the oscillations that $f(s)$ induces around them?

**ADDED:**

Tested many more zeros and the same pattern emerges. It is also visible at the first Lehmer pair $\gamma_{6709}, \gamma_{6710}$ i.e. $t=7005.06..., 7005.10...$. Between these closely adjacent zeros there still is a clear demarcation between the (fierce) oscillations around each zero (right graph). The red arrows indicate that when two zeros reside very close together, the "peak in the middle" is no longer 1 but shrinks to a very small "hill". Makes me wonder whether by establishing the "fierceness" of the oscillations around a $\rho_n$, we could roughly predict its distance to its neighbouring $\rho_{n+1}$? (note: graphs only show $\left(\Re(f(s)\right)$ ).

[image: Lehmer pair oscillations]